# how to create columns of different heights on different pages based on dynamic content using Itext7 and c#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, itext7

1. I have a PDF template that already has some content.
   [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jc-NAQySqE_BznQdf152OHyI1IOSjafT/view?usp=sharing)
2. I try to fill the columns with content (text and tables) but each page has a different column layout.

I tried to use an example on the Itext7 website ([Figure 2.13: Moving a column to the middle of the page](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-adding-content-canvas-or-document)) but it is for java. 
in c #, as in java, the UpdateCurrentArea method returns a LayoutArea type.

```
 return (currentArea = new LayoutArea(currentPageNumber,
    columns[nextAreaNumber++ % columns.length].clone()));
```

But in c# currentArea has RootLayoutArea type. Therefore, I can not return this value.

Who has any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: When do you know which page shall have which layout? Already at the beginning? Right before starting the respective page? While adding content to the page?

Comment: I collect all the data before writing to the document.

Comment: `RootLayoutArea` has been introduced in September/October 2017, both in Java and .Net. Apparently the documentation has not been updated yet... Have you tried using `new RootLayoutArea ...` instead of `new LayoutArea ...` yet? `RootLayoutArea` is derived from `LayoutArea`, so the return type still fits.

Comment: I'm sorry this is my carelessness... but the error is still there. all content is displayed in one column and each column on top of the other. Columns do not move.if I try to use FlushSingleRender the content completely disappears.